# WPF CodedUI Tests - how to stop test agent deploying a specific file?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, deployment, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Firstly, apologies if this has already been asked. I searched, but couldn't find anything specifically relating to this problem...

I'm having a big issue with CodedUI. In my case, I deploy my software to an environment, and then run the automated tests via visual studio on this environment. As the test starts, the test agent appears to copy files as it wishes into a temporary directory from which to run the tests, as suggested on this page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475(v=vs.100).aspx

> The following files and folders are copied to the deployment folder
>   before the tests are run:
>
> •The test assembly file
>
> •All dependent assemblies
>
> •Files that you have specified, such as XML files and configuration
>   files, on which tests depend. You can configure deployment both by
>   specifying additional deployment items to be copied and by changing
>   the deployment folder.

My issue with this is that my tests reference a file that is present on my environment. Into the directory

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\VSTT\12.0\UITestExtensionPackages"

I have placed an extension package that allows me to interface with some third-party WPF UI components. This is in place on the environment, and my test projects within Visual Studio all reference the file in that location as a dependency, and have "Copy Local" set to false and "Specific Version" set to true.

The problem occurs when the test agent starts the tests, and copies all of the files it thinks it requires to the temporary test directory. It also copies this extension file, resulting in every test failing with the error:

```
 System.InvalidCastException: [A]<type here> cannot be cast to [B]<same
 type here>
```

As it appears to be referencing the one I intentionally placed there as well as the one the agent copied over. If I manually go in and remove the file, then tests will start to pass.

My question is: how do I prevent the test agent from copying this file? I know the file will always be in the location which I placed it and do not require it to be copied over.

Comment: Are you using the DeploymentItem attribute in any of your test method ? If you are using, then can u check if u have specified your extension package as a deploymentitem in ANY of ur test methods under the Project ?

Comment: Nah, I'm not using that attribute in any test for the extensions (just for a few CSV files in the occasional test)